# Derive tile coordinates from tile number

Tags: mapbox, raster, mapbox-gl-js

I feel like this question has been answered before, but I'm off track somehow. I have the URL of a tile (see below): I see that the zoom level is 6, the 33th tile towards the east and 20th tile towards the south. My question is, can I deduct the lat/long (web mercator) coordinates of this tile using said numbers (33 / 20)?

https://heatmap-external-c.strava.com/tiles/all/hot/6/33/20@2x.png?v=19

[image: tile]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the tags of the question, the linked map is rendered via mapbox GL. In the [mapbox docs](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/static-tiles/#retrieve-raster-tiles-from-styles), I found a reference to the [OSM Slippy Map Tilenames specification](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames) which in turn provides the method with which to transform tilenames to lat long coordinates and vice versa. T[he following pseudocode](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Tile_numbers_to_lon..2Flat.) answers the question.

Tile numbers (`xtile`, `ytile`) to lon./lat for a given zoom level (`zoom`)

```
n = 2 ^ zoom
lon_deg = xtile / n * 360.0 - 180.0
lat_rad = arctan(sinh(π * (1 - 2 * ytile / n)))
lat_deg = lat_rad * 180.0 / π
```

Btw: this type of question is more commonly found on gis.stackexchange.com